# How can i make a model active/inactive without delete it, Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to deploy a way to active/inactive a model without delete it, like in User model that has a **is_active** field that we can deactivate a user, so I want to do same with whole model.

For example if I uncheck is_active in products model, this model will disappear! and all relation to products model was alternative with None.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a BaseModel class that has an is_active property that all your other models inherit from.

Next you will want to override the `delete` method on the BaseModel so that if delete is called, it inactivates it.  You can also add a `really_delete` function that calls the normal delete function if you really want to drop if from the DB.

```py
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def delete(self):
        self.is_active = False
        self.save()

    def undelete(self):
        self.is_active = True
        self.save(request=request)

    def really_delete(self):
        super().delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add is_active field and override the delete method.

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='is active?', default=True)
    remove_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='remove date', blank=True, null=True)

    def delete(self, purge=False, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        if purge:
            return super(TrackedModel, self).delete(using, keep_parents)
        else:
            self.remove_datetime = timezone.now()
            self.is_active = False
            self.save()
```

For tacking a model carefully I use these models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class TimedModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='created')
    modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="last modified")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not self.id:
            self.created = now
        self.modified = now
        return super(TimedModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        abstract = True


class TrackedModel(TimedModel):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='is active?', default=True)
    remove_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='remove date', blank=True, null=True)

    def delete(self, purge=False, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        if purge:
            return super(TrackedModel, self).delete(using, keep_parents)
        else:
            self.remove_datetime = timezone.now()
            self.is_active = False
            self.save()
```